# Simplifying multiple if else inside mutate for the same variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to clean up some data that is in the expr column. This is just a subset but there are many more rules that I have implemented. However, the method I am using shown below is very slow.

Is there any way to simplify this and make it more efficient?

Thanks

```r
df %>%
    mutate(expr = ifelse(entity == "Frequency",gsub( "twice daily", "2", expr), expr)) %>%
    mutate(expr = ifelse(entity == "Frequency",gsub( "twice a day", "2", expr), expr)) %>%
    mutate(expr = ifelse(entity == "Frequency",gsub( "once daily", "1", expr), expr)) %>%
    mutate(expr = ifelse(entity == "Frequency",gsub( "daily", "1", expr), expr))
```

Comment: Can you share (or produce) some representative data with `dput`?

Answer (score 1):

This is where `case_when` from `dplyr` absolutely shines, as it practically allows you to chain multiple `if`-statements.

The syntax is `case_when(logical ~ action)`. If the logical statement is true, the action will be performed.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(expr = case_when(
    entity == "Frequency" ~ gsub("twice (daily|a day)", "2", expr),
    entity == "Frequency" ~ gsub( "once daily", "1", expr),
    entity == "Frequency" ~ gsub( "daily", "1", expr)
  ))
```

Comment: You could simplify it to for example `gsub("twice (daily|a day)", "2", expr)`.

Comment: I agree, and will be editing my answer as my initial proposal would be less than ideal.

Comment: Thanks for the case_when suggestion, I've had a look at this, but am I correct in saying if the first condition is met, the other conditions won't be run?

Comment: Also, will this be any quicker than my original solution? Seems like it will still loop through the df for each condition?